# getting error when I try to use Drivers in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a custom driver in codeigniter, but i got error.

here is the File hierarchy:

```
 /libraries
    /libraries/Taker
        /libraries/Taker/Taker.php
        /libraries/Taker/drivers
            /libraries/Taker/drivers/Taker_test.php
```

Code in libraries/Taker/Taker.php:

```
   class Taker extends CI_Driver_Library  {
        function hello() {
            echo 123;
        }
    }
```

Code in libraries/Taker/drivers/Taker_test.php:

```
class Taker_test extends CI_Driver {
    function world() {
        echo 123;
    }
}
```

The code in the controller:

```
$this->load->driver('taker');
$this->taker->hello(); //work
$this->taker->test->world(); //eror here
```

the error i got in the controller:

```
Invalid driver requested: Taker_test
```

Any Suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that I had to use $this->valid_drivers:

```
class Taker extends CI_Driver_Library  {
    
    function __construct() {
          $this->valid_drivers = ['test'];
     }
    
    
    function hello() {
        echo 123;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @roev - this helped me a lot. I had the '$this->valid_drivers' line but was calling my driver with the full driver name ('Taker_test' rather than just 'test').